# How to find first img within the XML using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML code

```
<entry>
<p>11</p>
<p>22</p>
<p>33<img src="1.jpg"/></p>
<p>44</p>
</entry>
```

and I want to select the first image and get the src of it

The problem is because the img is not always at third child so its inside `<entry>` but I don't know exactly where it is,  so I need to search first image and not to find like this.

```
 p[2]->img[src]

 $children->entry->img[src];
```

Comment: Use the xpath method. Ex. $xml->xpath('img')  here $xml is the SimpleXMLElement's object

Comment: (Note: when adding XML or HTML elements inline in Stack Overflow, they must be `<formatted>` otherwise they will disappear - they are interpreted as HTML. I have edited your question to reveal `<entry>`).

Comment: @AlexanderChernin im getting  array()  - blank

Comment: I edited my comment - try it without the slash

Comment: same nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to find the `<img>` tag and extract the `src` attribute using `//img/@src` which finds any img element with a src attribute (using `@` to indicate it is an attribute)...

```
$data = '<entry>
<p>11</p>
<p>22</p>
<p>33<img src="1.jpg"></img></p>
<p>44</p>
</entry>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$image = $xml->xpath("//img/@src");
echo (string)$image[0];
```

will echo

```
1.jpg
```

As `xpath()` will return a list of matches, you need to use `[0]` to limit it to the first match and casting to a string (`(string)`) ensures you have a string as opposed to any form of SimpleXMLElement.

**Update:**

With the extra XML content in the real sample, there are a few more stages to get the images. A default namespace needs to be defined to allow you to fetch the content element - which contains the data you are after.  Then there are a few bits of manipulation of this data (remove some HTML which causes XML problems also as it's a document fragment, add in a new root element) and load this into a second level XML.  Then you can extract the src attributes.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("city.xml");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
$content = $xml->xpath("//d:content");
foreach ( $content as $cont )   {
    $newXML = "<root>".(string)$cont."</root>";
    $newXML = str_replace(["&nbsp;", "allowfullscreen"], " ", $newXML);
    $xml2 = simplexml_load_string($newXML);
    $image = $xml2->xpath("//img/@src");
    foreach ( $image as $imgSrc ){ 
        echo (string)$imgSrc.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: im not getting anything.   i also tried print_r($image) and i get Array ( )

Comment: Can you check the XML you have as this will make a big difference, update the question if it is different.

Comment: Is that all the XML?

Comment: bit.ly/2GLGKVN    here is all xml

Comment: foreach ($xml->entry as $children) { 
      echo $img= $children->xpath("//img/@src");


}

Comment: I will have to check this as the content is very different, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185919/discussion-between-gloytos-htyqo-and-nigel-ren).